# use a function in j position of data.table in R

Tags: r, regex, data.table

I've been having trouble using a function with it's argument being another column of of the same data.table.

```
pattern.1 <- regex("(?<=a)(.*)(?=c)")
  
DT <- data.table(x = c("abc", "adc", "abd"))
DT[, y := str_match(x, pattern.1)[1, 2]]

DT
```

for example, the above code give yield:

```
     x y
1: abc b
2: adc b
3: abd b
```

but the expected result is:

```
     x y
1: abc b
2: adc d
3: abd NA
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem, tks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve your problem as follow:

```
 DT[, y := str_extract(x, pattern.1)]
 # or (using str_match)
 DT[, y := str_match(x, pattern.1)[, 1]]

        x      y
   <char> <char>
1:    abc      b
2:    adc      d
3:    abd   <NA>
```

##### Remarks

1. `str_match` returns a matrix and not a vector; but in your problem,  you would like to get a vector.
2. You obtain `b` for all rows in column `y` in your result because you selected the first element of the second column of the matrix returned by `str_match`, which was then recycled. You should select *all* rows and the first column (`str_match(x, pattern.1)[, 1]`).
3. The function `str_extract` is more adapted to your problem because it returns a vector (see below)